# Python: what's the right way to initialize a variable (enum) imported before it's initialization

Tags: python, types, initialization, backend, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing some client code that uses a backend service to get some of the types that it uses.

Some of the types will be represented using an `Enum` in the code. However, these enums are being imported to the file before they have been initialized.

Here's an example similar to my code:

**types.py**

```
EnumA = None
EnumB = None

update_types():
    global EnumA
    global EnumB
    backend_types = get_backend_types(...)
    EnumA = Enum("A", backend_types["A"])
    EnumB = Enum("B", backend_types["B"])
```

**client.py**

```
from types import EnumA, EnumB, update_types

class Client:
    def setup(...):
        update_types()

    def some_method():
        # uses the enums here
        a = EnumA(1)
```

`Client.setup()` is called early on, but not early enough.

The problem is that when I get to execute `some_method`, `EnumA` is still `None` rather than initialized from the backend.

Adding a local import in `some_method` would solve that but I'd like to find a more generic solution.

Comment: Don't use `from` imports. I would recommend not having the initial `None` values at all, so `from` imports raise an error if they're attempted before the "real" values are set.

Comment: What library is being used to define Enums?

Comment: The built-in enum type. I'm on Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- import the module instead of the pieces:

```
      import types
      ...
      a = types.EnumA(1)
```

- move the call to `get_backend_types()` and `Enum` creation to module level instead of hiding them in a function:

```
      from enum import Enum
      ...
      backend_types = get_backend_types(...)
      EnumA = Enum("A", backend_types["A"])
      EnumB = Enum("B", backend_types["B"])
```